# Does the requests module play a part in pytest or pytest-qt?

Tags: python-requests, pyqt5, pytest, qt-signals, pytest-qt

This has cropped up in the course of some tests. I've tried to reproduce the problem in an MRE to isolate the problem but without success.

I have a test like this (simplified, but this simplified version manifests the same problem):

```
def test_if_index_already_exists_should_be_deleted(request, qtbot):
    response = requests.delete(f'http://localhost:9200/some_index')
```

... adding these 2 lines and running pytest results in a series of unexpected fails and errors. I'm using pytest-random-order, so they vary. The errors are the dreaded

> RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QTextEdit has been deleted

... but if I comment out the `requests.delete` line nothing happens: all tests pass fine with multiple random order runs.

Whether or not the index exists shouldn't be an issue (or indeed whether Elasticsearch is running). I'm a bit baffled.

A `QTextEdit` is present in my GUI, and a signal is used to update it. The trace info from pytest looks like this:

```
   File "/media/mike/software projects/EclipseWorkspace/doc_indexer/src/core/indexing_task_class.py", line 72, in set_extra_text
    self.extra_info_text_edit.setText(msg)
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QTextEdit has been deleted
```

This shows that a signal to update this GUI element is being fired when these tests fail. In response I have removed the signal and all references to it in the app and test code. After this the tests all pass OK.

Why could calling a command `requests.delete` cause what seems to be a spurious signal firing (apparently during teardown)? Does pytest-qt use `requests` in its internals perhaps?

PS deleting the `qtbot` fixture above does not solve the problem.

***Edit***

If I put `traceback.print_stack()` in the slot which gets fired I get this:

```
...
  File "/media/apps/Python/virtual_envs/doc_indexer/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytestqt/plugin.py", line 142, in pytest_runtest_setup
    _process_events()
  File "/media/apps/Python/virtual_envs/doc_indexer/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytestqt/plugin.py", line 182, in _process_events
    app.processEvents()
  File "/media/mike/software projects/EclipseWorkspace/doc_indexer/src/core/indexing_task_class.py", line 71, in set_extra_text
    traceback.print_stack()
Exceptions caught in Qt event loop:
________________________________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/mike/software projects/EclipseWorkspace/doc_indexer/src/core/indexing_task_class.py", line 72, in set_extra_text
    self.extra_info_text_edit.setText(msg)
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QTextEdit has been deleted
```

From the above it can be seen that the thing firing the signal is something inside pytestqt:

```
... /site-packages/pytestqt/plugin.py", line 182, in _process_events
```

That method looks like this:

```
def _process_events():
    """Calls app.processEvents() while taking care of capturing exceptions
    or not based on the given item's configuration.
    """
    app = qt_api.QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if app is not None:
        app.processEvents()
```

Comment: So: what did you discover when you traced which specific signal was being fired, and under what circumstances? The runtime-error indicates that references to the relevant objects aren't being managed properly; and/or that there's no mechanism for cleaning them up properly, or ensuring they're deleted in the right order. The python gc does not guarantee an order of deletion, so you should never take such things for granted,

Comment: Thanks. The thing is, I can't understand why these signals are being fired at all. Seeing as someone with your expertise has answered I'm going to add the stack trace from the slot which gets fired (if I add `traceback.print_stack()` to it).

Comment: What is the **actual name** of the signal that calls the slot? What does it normally do, and when would it normally get fired? If there are multiple emits, do they all cause the problem, or just one? What is the output of `print(repr(self.sender()))` from inside the slot?

Answer (score 0):

I think... this sort of error is almost always caused by failing to include the pytest-qt `qtbot` fixture when it needs to be included.

From my experiments, this is quite an insidious error, in the sense that test suites can pass many times without any error occurring... and then suddenly one appears to occur without any real clue from any console (or logging) output about what test method is the issue.

In particular, I am using the moddule [pytest-random-order](https://pythonhosted.org/pytest-random-order/), but I've also created a little script so I can do runs any number of times with a CLI switch. Typically therefore I may do the full test run 5 or so times so I can see when phenomena are occurring "intermittently". (In fact these turn out not to be intermittent: if I use the same `--random-order-seed` value I get the same horrible error: but using `pytest-random-order` obviously runs each run with a different seed, and therefore runs the test files in random order, and all the tests within them in random order).

The way I've had to identify this error is, then, by commenting out all my tests and gradually adding them back. More than once I've now found that it's a fairly new method which I added, without the `qtbot` fixture, which turned out to be the culprit.